# A GLM for estimating the covariate effects on the variance

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, variance

Suppose I have data for two or more groups which significantly vary in their variance but not in their means.

For example (simulated data in `R`):

```
set.seed(1)
df <- rbind(data.frame(group = rep("a",1000),y = rnorm(1000,0,1)),
            data.frame(group = rep("b",1000),y = rnorm(1000,0,2)))
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels = c("a","b"))
```

which densities look like this:
[image]

Are there families of GLMs which estimate the effect of covariates (`group` in this example) in the variance rather than the mean?

On the more sophisticated side, how about GLMs that estimate effects both on the mean and the variance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should look for distributional models. This type of model fit an equation for each parameter of the distribution. In your case, the mean parameter would get only an intercept while the variance parameter would get covariates. In R, you should probably start with the [gamlss](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gamlss/index.html) package.